# Create Dropping Effect for colored discs in Connect4 game Javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to create a JavaFx app for Connect4 game. I need some suggestions in showing how colored disc would fall in each column, kind of showing colored disc in each white section for a quick span and then fall further down.

I have created 7 columns of VBox's with 6 Circles inside each column. All columns then are embedded in a giant HBox.

[image]

So when player clicks on a column, the disc falls from top. To show dropping of disc I tried:

```
protected boolean fillColumnWithPlayerColor(VBox col) {

    ObservableList<Node> discs = col.getChildren();

    for (int i = discs.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Circle circle = (Circle) discs.get(i);

        if (circle.getFill().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
            if (i > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    Circle prevCircle = (Circle) discs.get(j);//Assigning the current disc to player color
                    prevCircle.setFill(playerColor); //playerColor -> Color chosen by player
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(800); //Delay for display
                        prevCircle.setFill(Color.WHITE); //Setting the color back to White
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            circle.setFill(playerColor);
            return true;

        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

But no matter what the delay duration is (Thread.sleep), the disc just shows at its final place after total duration, not the "dropping" effect.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You cannot use Thread.sleep for this.  Doing so prevents JavaFX from processing events, including painting events and processing of user input.  Use an [animation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use Thread.sleep() in JavaFX. You're defining a path for your circle to follow so you should be using the Path Transition package.

```
 import javafx.animation.transition.*;
 ...
      Path path = new Path();
      path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(0f, 50f));
      pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(800));
      pathTransition.setNode(circle);
      pathTransition.setPath(path);
      pathTransition.play();
```

For more help refer yourself to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html)